# Translating java into javascript using compareTo

Tags: javascript, java, string, compareto

I have some code that compares two strings and returns the one with the lowest value, then compares that value to the letterGrade to see which one is the lowest and then returns the higher of the two. My issue is that I am having issues getting this code to work using javascript. 
Javascript code:

```
    var result1 = (finalexam.getletterGrade().compareTo(midexam.getletterGrade()));
    var result2 = " ";
    if (result1 == 0)
    {
        result2 = midexam.getletterGrade();
    }
    else if (result1 < 0)
    {
        result2 = midexam.getletterGrade();
    }
    else if (result1 > 0)
    {
        result2 = finalexam.getletterGrade();
    }
    var result3 = (letterGrade.compareTo(result2));
    if (result3 < 0)
    {
        result2 = letterGrade;
    }
```

Comment: If you want to fix your Javascript; post the Javascript, not the Java.

Comment: What have you tried in javascript? Also note that javascript and java are not closely related languages, copy and paste is not going to work.

Comment: I have edited my question with the javascript code. I have tried localeCompare which did not work. CompareTo is the only way I know to solve this problem and cannot get it to work in javascript.

Comment: `My issue is that I am having issues ...` Please, give an explanation. What exactly doesn't work? Can you show sample input that breaks this code?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript `int` doesn't have a ternary `compareTo` like Java. You could write one. Something like,

```
function compare(a, b) {
    if (a < b) {
        return -1;
    } else if (a > b) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then change your `compareTo` calls to invoke it. Something like

```
var result1 = compare(finalexam.getletterGrade(), midexam.getletterGrade());
```

and

```
var result3 = compare(letterGrade, result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

my issue was that our backend code sorted our content using Java's compareTo, because of a misunderstanding I attempted to rewrite compareTo in JavaScript, whereas the fix ended up something completely different, however this may solve your issue

```
String.prototype.compareTo = function (anotherString) {
    var len1 = this.length;
    var len2 = anotherString.length;
    var n = Math.min(len1,len2); //If the lengths will always be the same skip n to be assigned to len1 only, get rid of len2
    var v1 = this;
    var v2= new String(anotherString);
    // You could instead set these vars i and j to passed in offsets if you want to start sorting from, in which case else case will be possible, or only the first i == j if statement will always be run
    var i = 0; 
    var j = 0;

    if (i == j) {
        var k = i;
        var lim = n + i;
        while (k < lim) {
            var c1 = v1[k];
            var c2 = v2[k];
            if (c1 != c2) {
                var returnVal = c1.charCodeAt(0) - c2.charCodeAt(0);
                if (returnVal > 0) 
                    return 1;
                else
                    return -1
                return 0;
            }
            k++;
        }
    } else {
        while (n-- != 0) {
            var c1 = v1[i++];
            var c2 = v2[j++];
            if (c1 != c2) {
                var returnVal = c1.charCodeAt(0) - c2.charCodeAt(0);
                if (returnVal > 0) 
                    return 1;
                else
                    return -1
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return len1 - len2; 
    //return 0; //if lengths are always the same, comment the above line, uncomment this line
}
```

Call it like below

```
var a = "whatever";
var b = "however";
a.compareTo(b);
```

Hope this helps