# How to do <=> in JS? (compare with -1 0 1)

Tags: javascript

I would like to do `a <=> b` in JS but apparently that operator does not exist, is there a function equivalent?

Thanks,
Dorian

Comment: It'd probably require manual implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33490681/translating-java-into-javascript-using-compareto

Comment: BTW not the DV: operators are hard to google search for, esp for SO answers, I'm not surprised you didn't find the dupe (I didn't either, someone else pointed it out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic implementation of the behavior of the "spaceship" operator in JavaScript.

```js
const spaceship = (lhs, rhs) =>  lhs < rhs ? -1 : rhs < lhs ? 1 : 0;
```

If you want to add some extra type-checking, you can use the `typeof` operator to add some custom comparison logic.

**Note:** The `localeCompare` method return `-1`, `0`, or `1`. Comparators in JavaScript act like the `<==>` operator. They are used when sorting arrays.

```js
const spaceship = (lhs, rhs) => {
  const type = typeof lhs;
  if (type !== typeof rhs) { throw new Error('types do not match') }
  if (type === 'string') { return lhs.localeCompare(rhs); }
  else if (type === 'number') { return Math.sign(lhs - rhs); }
  return lhs < rhs ? -1 : rhs < lhs ? 1 : 0;
}

mocha.setup('bdd')
const { expect } = chai

describe('spaceship operator', () => {
  it('integer comparison', () => {
    expect(spaceship(1, 1)).to.equal( 0); // 1 <=> 1 ===  0
    expect(spaceship(1, 2)).to.equal(-1); // 1 <=> 2 === -1
    expect(spaceship(2, 1)).to.equal( 1); // 2 <=> 1 ===  1
  });
  it('float comparison', () => {
    expect(spaceship(1.5, 1.5)).to.equal( 0); // 1.5 <=> 1.5 ===  0
    expect(spaceship(1.5, 2.5)).to.equal(-1); // 1.5 <=> 2.5 === -1
    expect(spaceship(2.5, 1.5)).to.equal( 1); // 2.5 <=> 1.5 ===  1
  });
  it('string comparison', () => {
    expect(spaceship('a', 'a')).to.equal( 0) // 'a' <=> 'a' ===  0
    expect(spaceship('a', 'b')).to.equal(-1) // 'a' <=> 'b' === -1
    expect(spaceship('b', 'a')).to.equal( 1) // 'b' <=> 'a' ===  1
  });
  it('date comparison', () => {
    const today = new Date(), yestr = new Date(today.getTime() - 8.64e7);
    expect(spaceship(today, today)).to.equal( 0) // 'a' <=> 'a' ===  0
    expect(spaceship(yestr, today)).to.equal(-1) // 'a' <=> 'b' === -1
    expect(spaceship(today, yestr)).to.equal( 1) // 'b' <=> 'a' ===  1
  });
})

mocha.run()
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/2.3.4/mocha.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/3.4.1/chai.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/2.3.4/mocha.js"></script>
<div id="mocha"></div>
```